# Plot multiple lines with a character as x-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a daily time series that runs across several years. I would like a plot for each year, on the same graf.

So, I have all my dates of the year, in the format %m-%d and a single point for each year.

Data example:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2013-01-01"), 
                                 to = as.Date("2016-10-01"), by = "day"), 
                 xv = rnorm(1370))

# First I add my x-axis (Days) and my factor variable (Year)
df <- df %>% mutate(Year = format(Date, "%Y"), 
                    Days = format(Date, "%m-%d")) %>% select(Date, Year, Days, xv)
```

Essentially it should sort like this: (Except Year shouldn't be on the x-axis)
[image]

Now, I can easily do a faceted plot, but this contains empty space for the following year, which I don't want, and I also really would like all lines on the same graph.

```
# Wrong faceted graph
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = xv, group = Year, colour = Year)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(.~Year)
```

I've tried variations of setting group = 1, so you can plot using a character/factor as x-variable, but then you can't plot more than one line. Data can contain missing variables or incomplete days (leap-years and such). I would really prefer a ggplot solution.

Comment: Why not use the variable `Days` you created ? `ggplot(df, aes(x = Days, y = xv, group = Year, colour = Year)) + geom_line()`

Comment: I tried that... Have no idea why I couldn't get it to work!

Comment: Is it still not working? it seems to work fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `facet_wrap` combined with `scales = 'free_x'`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = xv, group = Year, colour = Year)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Year, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]